# Google Analytics API Easy Dashboard Javascript Library

Tags: google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I want to use the Google Analytics API to show analytics data in our CMS.
As every website runs the CMS under their own domain like domain.com/cms I do not want to use webapplication API access. I want to use a API Service Accounts, so there is no domain check using the API, in stead it uses a client id (different from webapplication access) and a private key.

So far, so good. I set up the connection with the API and I can read google analytics data.
But I would like to show some charts.

Easy Dashboard Javascript Library is very handy, but it uses webapplication API access, so it checks the URL where it is called from. And I don't want this. Is there a way to simply create charts (with this library or another), and using Service Account API access?

Comment: Do each of your websites/domains have their own GA tracking code or are you using a master GA account?

Comment: Every domain has its own GA tracking code. But I already found a solution with a service account. I use a jquery charts component to get things done. Thanks anyway

Comment: Solutions are very handy when it comes to people looking up the same thing you were posting about. Many months later, I have the same issue but I don't know how to solve it since this thread has no answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from your Google Analytics Service Account and use the data to create charts using the many libraries available using javascript or jquery.
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/